# Magento export returns a blank screen

Tags: magento-1.9, export

I am using version 1.9.  When I click on System->Import/Export->Export I am presented with a screen where I can chose Entity Type and Export File Format.  From the Entity Type drop down box I chose Products.  And from the Export File Format drop down box I chose CSV.  I am then presented with a list of entity attributes that I can exclude from the export.  I don't chose to skip any of them, I want all of the attributes exported.  I then click on Continue.  After about 45 seconds, the screen goes blank.  That's it.  No export.

We had this same behavior when we were using version 1.7.  We upgraded to 1.9 in the hopes that the upgrade would fix the problem.

What is wrong with the export function?  It did work for a long time while we were using version 1.7.

Comment: Is there anything in the log files?

Comment: How much products and attributes does your webshop have?

Comment: @JohnTranter - Where would I find the log files?

Comment: @DmitryR: We have about 5000 products and about 200 attributes.

Comment: Can you check that max_execution_time is enough to process all the products?

Comment: @DmitryR: The value is 18000.  I get the blank screen back in about 45 seconds.

Comment: Could be a memory issue. You could increase it in php.ini:

`memory_limit = 64M`

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem. 
Don't know why but for some reason my database has some products with no (NULL) SKU. went to myphpadmin, delete those products and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Enable developer mode mode in Magento and try to reproduce the error. It will shows more details about the source of the issue.

Comment: I set System->Configuration->Developer->Log Settings->Enable to Yes.  I found only one file in the directory public_html/var/log named system.log.  That file contained only one line: 2015-02-05T05:59:06+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined offset: 3078  in public_html/app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Entity/Product.php on line 875

Comment: As I said, developer mode will give you much more details about the source or the problem.
You can enable it following steps described in here:
http://alanstorm.com/magento_exception_handling_developer_mode

Comment: Thanks for the directions.  The contents of the exception file are too long to be posted here.  How can I get you to see it?  I will post as much as I can: `2015-02-06T03:05:18+00:00 ERR (3):
exception 'Exception' with message 'Notice: Undefined offset: 3078  in public_html/app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Entity/Product.php on line 875' in public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php:245
Stack trace:
#0 public_html/app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Entity/Product.php(875): mageCoreErrorHandler(8, 'Undefined offse...', 'public_html/app...', 875, Array)
#1 public_ht`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have rights for the export folder set properly? Set them to 777 if you're not sure. Have you changed the default path and filename of the export? Change them back and remove existing files with that filename in the export folder.

I don't see an entity export in my admin, but for product export I see something like this:

- Path: var/export
- Filename: export_product.xml

I know we had similar problems, but that was more than a year ago and I don't remember the exact details. We're using Magento 1.7.

Comment: What would the path be to the export folder?

Comment: In the root of magento you have the var folder. Inside that folder is the export folder. If that doesn't exist, create it and give Magento or Apache the proper rights to write to that folder: `chmod -R 777 var/export`

Comment: The export directory did not exist, so I created it with the specified permissions, but it behaved the same.  Nothing was produced and just a blank screen is returned.

Comment: What do you see in the Apache logs when you do the export?